# Помогите поменять регистр

Tags: php, joomla

Поиск по сайту чувствителен к регистру , но как это поменять я не могу понять. Не могу понять  ,что за бинарная кодировка. Этоо плагин joomla [com_search](https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/joomla-example/blob/master/php/components/com_search/views/search/view.html.php)

Помогите пожалуйста

Код PHP:

```
for ($i = 0, $count = count($results); $i < $count; $i++)
            {
                $row = & $results[$i]->text;

                if ($state->get('match') == 'exact')
                {
                    $searchwords = array($searchword);
                    $needle      = $searchword;
                }
                else
                {
                    $searchworda = preg_replace('#\xE3\x80\x80#s', ' ', $searchword);
                    $searchwords = preg_split("/\s+/u", $searchworda);
                    $needle      = $searchwords[0];
                }
```

Comment: Похоже на юникод. Например, \xE3 это http://www.charbase.com/00e3-unicode-latin-small-letter-a-with-tilde

Comment: В вопросе вы указали код для формирования аргументов поиска. Сам код поиска не привели. Не удивительно, что вы не понимаете, как поправить поиск.

Answer (score 0):

вы бы хоть переменные описали, ничего не понятно...

```
$str = "Mary Had A Little Lamb and She LOVED It So";
$str = strtolower($str);
echo $str; // выводит: mary had a little lamb and she loved it so
```

применяете strtolower($str) как для запрошенной строки, так и для сравниваемых значений.

Comment: Для кириллицы и utf-8 лучше [mb-strtolower](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strtolower.php)